# I want to deploy a simple rest API to webspphere application server

Tags: websphere-8

I have not worked on websphere aplication server, i have a simple rest api i want to deploy that to websphere application server.

need to know the detailed configuration of the websphere application server from scratch

want to understand how the websphere application server works, what are the ports number that are configured, how to access the logs if i am having any issues with the code of starting up the server.

Comment: There is a guide that provides additional details to @Gas's post: 
https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html 

It uses Open Liberty as the deployment server, but the application code in that guide should work with WAS 9.x (based on JAX-RS 2.0). HTH

Answer (score 1):

Kind of broad question. WebSphere dosn't have anything special here. Just use standard Java EE rest apis, dont use Spring as it doesnt bring any additional value.

So simplified steps:

- Create class with `@ApplicationPath("/api")`
- Create service class with `@Path("/hello")`
- implement methods e.g.

  `@GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String getHello() {
      return "Hello from rest ";
  }`
- package as war
- install on server (if on tWAS via admin console, if on WebSphere Liberty put to `dropins`)
- access via http://localhost:9080/warfileName/api/hello  (assuming default installation ports)

Comment: Appreciate your response! I am aware of building rest API's but i have not worked on Websphere APplication server, so i wanted to build a simple get service which responds to a call and the application is deployed on the websphere application server.
I was going through the IBM posts and some youtube videos but couldn't find a simple video for deploying a java(EAR file) to websphere application server

Comment: I am i have a hughe application deployed on the websphere application server but i am getting following exception
[1/14/19 10:54:28:600 EST] 00000063 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Apps\Eclipse_Neon\AppServer_1\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_64d76794_19.01.14_10.54.28.5957899293159791815555.txt HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation 2
and when i look at the logs i do not see that file generated in that location.